# about HashMap.get(key) function

Tags: java, hashmap

If I pull out an object out of my HashMap, and then modify it. Will it modify inside the HashMap also? Or, do I need to set it back again to the HashMap after modifying it?

For example:

```
HashMap<Integer,TwoPoints> loc = new HashMap<Integer,TwoPoints>();
...
...
TwoPoints tp = loc.get(Id); //pulls out the object
tp.setPoint(group, new Point(x,y); //a method to set something inside the object I pulled.
```

Comment: Try it and see....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are getting a reference to the actual object, so any change would be reflected in it. You are not creating a copy.

**Update:**

Since I used the term "reference", I thought it is important to point out the definition. Under Java's hood, things are not quite as simple as this. But a reference (what you are doing) is getting the **value** of the **pointer** to the object.

Comment: The same applies in all other cases as well: pulling an object out of an array or other types of Collection, passing the object to a method, having multiple variables point to the same object and so on.